# Magento 2 : About us page is not displaying on front end

Tags: magento2, frontend, page

I added about us page using content -> pages option, Page has been created but in front end I can't able find any link to access that page.

I directly access through the url (localhost/home/about-us) it works well.

Can anyone help me to fix that issue.

Comment: what is your magento root directory?

Comment: http://localhost/home/

I created root directory as home.

Comment: Please check out this link to create contact us page in magento 2. https://magenticians.com/how-to-setup-magento-2-contact-us-page/

Comment: so on the front end where you need that link? in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the **Search Engine Optimisation** > **URL** Key is set to **about-us** and that Page in websites is correctly associated with your store view.

For more info, please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254609/magento2-content-pages-are-not-working-on-frontend)

Comment: I followed the instruction but not working.

Answer (score 0):

As you shared this url 
localhost/home/about-us
is working well. Then you need to add this url in footer/menu. Then whenever you want you can access it